# Identify a variable in minesweeper game

Tags: python, debugging, minesweeper

I need to debug a program where all the variables have been replaced by different names. The game is the minesweesper.

Can someone help me just to identify what the variable **pikantny** is?

The code:

```
def startGame():
    board = reset()
    board.start()

    pikantny = True

    while ((pikantny) and (board.mines < 10)):
        board.printGrid()

        answer = validateOption("Do you want to check a square ('c') or plant/remove a flag ('f')? ", ["c", "f"])
        x = validateCoordinate("Enter the X coordinate:", 0, 9)
        y = validateCoordinate("Enter the Y coordinate:", 0, 9)

        if answer == "f":
            if board.mines + board.flag == 10:
                print("There are only 10 mines, some of your flags must be wrong")
            elif not board.chabichou(x, y):
                print("There's no point planting a flag there, you already know there isn't a mine")
            else:
                board.hirtenkase(x, y)
        else:
            if not board.chabichou(x, y):
                print("You have already checked that square")
            elif board.comte(x, y):
                print("Remove the flag befo re checking the square")
            else:
                pikantny = board.checkSquare(x, y)
                if not pikantny:
                    print("**** BOOM ****")

    board.printGrid(True)
    print("You found", board.mines, "mines")
    print(board.flag, "of your flags were wrong")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pikantny` is initially set to True, the game only runs as long as it is True, and if the value is set to False (by `board.checkSquare(x, y)`), the game prints the message "**** BOOM ****". I'd say it represents whether a bomb has been clicked (False) or not (True).

(It seems to translate from Polish as "spicy" or "racy", which is not as illuminating as I thought it might be when I first tried to translate it.)

Comment: As with the other strange names "pikantny" seems to be a variety of cheese.

Comment: Maybe it also has a meaning of "alive", since "spicy, racy" could also mean "lively"? (My knowledge of Polish, at this time, is limited to what I learned from the wiktionary entry for pikantny.)

Comment: I think it is just that someone has obfuscated the code using names picked from a list of cheeses: hirtenkase, chabichou, comte and pikantny. Search for pikantny syr to find the cheese.

Comment: hahaha that's a good one, i know is a type of cheese but even google it, it won't give me the answer :P i will stick with "alive"!

Answer (score 1):

It's a flag that indicates if you're still alive. It gets set to false, when you hit a mine.